# Integrate Rasa with Microsoft Teams

Tags: python, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, rasa-nlu

I am trying to connect Rasa chatbot on python to Microsoft Teams application. Because of its UI and organization wide implementation.

I have referred [Rasa Community question](https://forum.rasa.com/t/connect-rasa-bot-to-microsoft-teams/21340/5).

1. I have setup ngrok server locally on HTTPS
2. Connected a dummy application from Teams on nodejs

But I am unable to connect on Rasa. Any leads would be appreciated

**Update**
As suggested in the comments, I have also developed Local teams EchoBot. But I am unable to communicate between Teams EchoBot and Rasa.

Comment: Can you please go through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-nodejs-app-studio#download-the-sample) to set up sample application locally. Please let me know if you face any issue to set it locally.

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT thank you for the comment. Yes I have followed that application. It works, but there is no documentation I could find on sending Rasa replies to Teams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the [docs for connecting Rasa to Microsoft Bot Framework](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/connectors/microsoft-bot-framework/#running-on-microsoft-bot-framework) you need to include the following in your `credentials.yml` file:

```
botframework:
  app_id: "MICROSOFT_APP_ID"
  app_password: "MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD"
```